# Output showing null values. how to resolve 

Tags: java

i have three classes :

### CustomerData.java

```
import java.util.Date;
public class CustomerData 
{
   private String FirstName;
   private String LastName;
   private int TaxId;
   private String HomePhone;
   private String WorkPhone;
   private String HomeAddress;
private Date Dob;
private String EmployerName;
private boolean isEmployed;
private String ProDescription;
private String IsSameAsPrevious;

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}
public int getTaxId() {
    return TaxId;
}
public void setTaxId(int taxId) {
    TaxId = taxId;
}
public String getHomePhone() {
    return HomePhone;
}
public void setHomePhone(String homePhone) {
    HomePhone = homePhone;
}
public String getWorkPhone() {
    return WorkPhone;
}
public void setWorkPhone(String workPhone) {
    WorkPhone = workPhone;
}
public String getHomeAddress() {
    return HomeAddress;
}
public void setHomeAddress(String homeAddress) {
    HomeAddress = homeAddress;
}
public Date getDob() {
    return Dob;
}
public void setDob(Date dob) {
    Dob = dob;
}
public String getEmployerName() {
    return EmployerName;
}
public void setEmployerName(String employerName) {
    EmployerName = employerName;
}
public boolean isEmployed() {
    return isEmployed;
}
public void setEmployed(boolean isEmployed) {
    this.isEmployed = isEmployed;
}
public String getProDescription() {
    return ProDescription;
}
public void setProDescription(String proDescription) {
    ProDescription = proDescription;
}
public String getIsSameAsPrevious() {
    return IsSameAsPrevious;
}
public void setIsSameAsPrevious(String isSameAsPrevious) {
    IsSameAsPrevious = isSameAsPrevious;
}
```

}

### MainCntrlr.java

```
public class MainCntrlr {
             public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    CustomerData customerData=new CustomerData();
    customerData.setFirstName("RAVI");
    customerData.setLastName("Shekhar");
    customerData.setHomePhone("123456789");
    customerData.setWorkPhone("1256554634");
    customerData.setHomeAddress("Banagalore");
    customerData.setEmployerName("ABc");
    customerData.setProDescription("New Produtc");
    customerData.setTaxId(1233434343);



    ContrOne ctr=new ContrOne();
    ctr.displayInformation();
        }
}
```

### ContrOne.java

```
import com.blr.CustomerData;
public class ContrOne 
{
  public void displayInformation()
  {
CustomerData cd=new CustomerData();
System.out.println("displaying customer Info");

System.out.println(cd.getFirstName());
System.out.println(cd.getLastName());
System.out.println(cd.getHomePhone());
System.out.println(cd.getWorkPhone());
System.out.println(cd.getEmployerName());
System.out.println(cd.getProDescription());
System.out.println(cd.getDob());
System.out.println(cd.getTaxId());


  }
}
```

Output is :

```
displaying customer Info
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
0
```

Comment: Exactly @Jon Skeet, hence why I offered to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `CustomerData` object  in `MainCntrlr` class but not passing it to the `ContrOne` class. `ContrOne` is creating it's own `CustomerData` object and printing it's values which are null.

A possible solution could be to change the signature of `displayInfo` and pass the `CustomerData` object to this method from MainCntrlr class.

A few other points to note

1. The class names are confusing. It is not clear why you have created `MainCntrlr` and `ContrOne` classes separately.
2. If all you want is to display Customer information, you may want to override the `toString`() method in `CustomerData` class instead.

Comment: Option 2 isn't feasible at all, because on `ContrOne.displayInformation()` the `CustomerData cd` `toString()` method will still display nulls and zero where applicable, i.e. the fields of `cd` must be populated first.

Comment: I mentioned Option 2 just as a better design for printing the attributes of CustomerData object rather than having that logic in a separate displayInfo() method.

Comment: I understand that, but if the OP wants to change `OutputStream`, option 2 won't help at all. That's how I also look at it.

Answer (score 7):

In your method `ContrOne.displayInformation()` you create a new `new CustomerData()` object. Thus it is not properly initialized. Maybe you want to pass `customerData` from your `main` method to `displayInformation`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `ContrOne.displayInformation()` instantiates a new `CustomerData()` object to `cd` but **never** populates fields in it.

If you want your `ContrOne` to display information, rather do this:

```
public class ContrOne {

    public void displayInformation(CustomerData cd)  {
        System.out.println("displaying customer Info");

        System.out.println(cd.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(cd.getLastName());
        System.out.println(cd.getHomePhone());
        System.out.println(cd.getWorkPhone());
        System.out.println(cd.getEmployerName());
        System.out.println(cd.getProDescription());
        System.out.println(cd.getDob());
        System.out.println(cd.getTaxId());
    }
}
```

and in `MainCntrlr`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomerData customerData=new CustomerData();
    customerData.setFirstName("RAVI");
    customerData.setLastName("Shekhar");
    customerData.setHomePhone("123456789");
    customerData.setWorkPhone("1256554634");
    customerData.setHomeAddress("Banagalore");
    customerData.setEmployerName("ABc");
    customerData.setProDescription("New Produtc");
    customerData.setTaxId(1233434343);

    ContrOne ctr=new ContrOne();
    ctr.displayInformation(customerData);
}
```

Comment: @ravi .. especially if you want help in the future. :)